# Building mdadm tool for android platform

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I have downloaded mdadm source code from below location
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/raid/mdadm/

Copied these files at /system/extras/mdadm

And, added Android.mk file for the executable binary of mdadm.

But, I am seeing following error when I compiled it:

```
target thumb C: mdadm <= system/extras/mdadm/sg_io.c
**arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files**
compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/target/product/<prod_name>/obj/EXECUTABLES/mdadm_intermediates/sg_io.o] Error 1
```

Any pointers to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

My Android.mk file looks like

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> mdadm_src_files :=  Build.c mdopen.c mdmon.c monitor.c \
>
> managemon.c util.c  maps.c mdstat.c \
>
> sysfs.c policy.c lib.c Kill.c sg_io.c \
>
> dlink.c super0.c super1.c super-intel.c \
>
> super-mbr.c super-gpt.c super-ddf.c sha1.c \
>
> crc32.c msg.c bitmap.c xmalloc.c platform-intel.c \
>
> probe_roms.c config.c Manage.c Assemble.c Create.c Detail.c \
>
> Examine.c Grow.c Monitor.c Query.c Incremental.c Dump.c
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(mdadm_src_files)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE := mdadm
>
> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libc
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../kernel/include/
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=
>   $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../kernel/arch/arm/include/asm/*
>
> include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)